# RSS API in Forex calendar

Tags: php, rss, calendar, forex

how can i integrate this into my website using PHP?

http://www.forex-tsd.com/fxcalendar.php?p=csv

And getting this result:

http://www.forex-tsd.com/fxcalendar.php?p=calendar&objID=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the `explode();` php function to cut the received data.

Answer (score 0):

So I take it that you already know how to get the csv of the information you want. PHP Classes is full of lots of classes you can use to parse csv files. There are loads of them, so choose the one you like the best.

There are classes for parsing and reading, and classes that import the csv into a database.

http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=csv&go_search=1&x=0&y=0

Comment: I solved it in another way. But thank you for your answer @desbest